# How can I display by default image in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have multiple images and onClick that will be display in another div this is working fine in React but now I want to display first image by default in another div, how can I do that?

My code:

```js
render() {

    const imageClick = (selectedImg) => {
      this.setState({ selectedImg })
    }
    return (

      <div>

        <img src="images/1.png" onClick={() => imageClick(1)} />
        <img src="images/2.png" onClick={() => imageClick(2)} />
        <img src="images/1.png" onClick={() => imageClick(1)} />
        <img src="images/2.png" onClick={() => imageClick(2)} />

        <div className="newDiv">
          <img src={`images/${this.state.selectedImg}.png`} /> // Get the selected image from this.state
</div>

      </div>
    )
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to set the initial state of image to `1` . For default the will load the first image to div

```
state = {
  selectedImg:1
}
```